# Arduino Uno board not recognized in IDE. Board is not in device manager!

Tags: arduino-uno

My arduino uno is not recognized by the Arduino IDE. I'm using 1.8.0, The IDE is not showing the COM. The tool section is showing only COM 1, i.e. the hardware.

I opened Device manager, there is no board for UNO.

Help me please.

[image]

[image]

Arduino Nano works fine.

I have CH340 driver already installed. My computer do not make any "hardware connected sound". I have 3 arduino IDE versions - 1.8.0, 1.8.9, 1.8.10!.

Comment: Bad cable, or power only cable, will show the same thing. Try another one.

Comment: If you unplug/plug the USB cable, you might hear the typical "new device" sound. If yes, and there's a unknown usb device appearing,  it's not a real Arduino Uno, and you need an extra usb driver for it.  ( CH340 instead of 16U2 )

Comment: Even when I unplug/plug the USB cable, the computer do not make any sound and in addition, it do not even seem to affect the screen at all.(Do not show any change in IDE or Device Manager).

Comment: My arduino nano works fine & my computer do have an CH340 driver already for my Nano board.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Arduino. My solution is to unplug it, replug it and do what you need to do before the computer can auto-configure it. 
I hope it helps! :)
BTW make sure you are choosing the right board.

Comment: I really uninstalled and reinstalled arduino ide because of this problem. I tried replugging my board then too it does not work.

Comment: And I also have 3 Arduino IDE versions:- 1.8.0, 1.8.9, 1.8.10

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoUno, you may need to install a separate driver for the Arduino Uno because it does not have a true USB port. The details are in the link.

Comment: My arduino UNO chip says AtMega16u2..A97VB.